# Why using capacitor in transformer less ac to dc converter

Tags: power-supply, ac, transformerless, capacitive-power-supply

I saw many transformer-less power supplies using capacitive resistance of a capacitor.

But I don't know exactly what the reasons are for using capacitors instead of normal resistors .

I guess two reasons:

- Capacitors are more isolated than resistors.
- Capacitive resistance waste less power (is it right ?)

Comment: both are right, but it depends on the load. have you looked into how they work?

Comment: capacitors don't turn 100% of excess power into heat like resistors do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resisters waste lots of power .Capacitors and inducters waste much less power .At 50Hz the inducter would be expensive,Bulky and heavy .Hence the capacitor .